# How to connect to wifi using swift 3 in ios 9 and ios 10 devices?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

As per my requirement I have to connect to a WiFi sharing device(own company product) with an iOS app. In iOS 11 I have achieved it by using `NEHotspotConfiguration`But I am not able to achieve it in iOS 9 and iOS 10. WiFi device is having an ssid(fixed) and iOS app also configured with it. To connect to this device I need to use device ssid only. I have searched a lot for this solution and my findigs are

- It's not possible due to security risks involved in it.
- Through private api Apple80211 it is possible but you can't do this, at least not if you want to be able to publish on the App Store.
- NEHotspotHelper it is possible but need to get entitlements from **Apple** for that need to send mail and wait till response.

Is anyone know any way like how to tackle this problem without going for third approach(above) by using only ssid in language swift 3.